# filtro de sql em outra tabela

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Bom dia,

Estou com um problema onde tenho o seguinte código funcionando.

```
select 
(sum((case when (lanc.id_tipo = 1 OR lanc.id_tipo = 5) 
then lanc.valor else 0 end)) + sum((case when (lanc.id_tipo = 2) 
then lanc.valor else 0 end))) AS Saldo
from lancamentos lanc
where lanc.id_situacao = 1 or lanc.id_situacao = 3 or lanc.id_situacao = 5
group by id_contas
```

Eu preciso inserir um filtro, só que fica em outra tabela do banco, tenho a tabela contas e uma coluna chamada `id_tipo_conta` eu precisaria que ele somasse somente o tipo 1, e não consigo colocar esse filtro dentro desse código.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Presume-se que exista algum tipo de ligação entre estas duas tabelas (lancamentos e contas), talvez uma chave estrangeira? Se existir é só fazer um INNER JOIN.

Comment: Adicione um left join com a tabela de contas, ai você pode filtrar por tipo de conta na cláusula where.

Comment: Sim tem sim o cod da conta como chave estrangeira...

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer assim,

select lanc.id_contas,
sum((case when (lanc.id_tipo = 1 OR lanc.id_tipo = 5) 
then lanc.valor else 0 end)) AS Receitas,
sum((case when (lanc.id_tipo = 2) 
then lanc.valor else 0 end)) AS Despesas,
(sum((case when (lanc.id_tipo = 1 OR lanc.id_tipo = 5) 
then lanc.valor else 0 end)) + sum((case when (lanc.id_tipo = 2) 
then lanc.valor else 0 end))) AS Saldo
from lancamentos lanc
LEFT JOIN contas AS f ON f.id_tipo_conta = 1 where lanc.id_situacao = 1 or lanc.id_situacao = 3 or lanc.id_situacao = 5 
group by lanc.id_contas

Só que os dados ficaram com os dados errados porque o "where lanc.id_situacao = 1 or lanc.id_situacao = 3 or lanc.id_situacao = 5" não ficou certo, não consigo fazer o where correto com o LEFT JOIN contas AS f ON f.id_tipo_conta = 1

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver com esse código.

```
select lanc.id_contas,
(sum((case when (lanc.id_tipo = 1 OR lanc.id_tipo = 5 or lanc.id_tipo = 4) 
then lanc.valor else 0 end)) + sum((case when (lanc.id_tipo = 2 or lanc.id_tipo = 3) 
then lanc.valor else 0 end))) AS Saldo
from lancamentos lanc
LEFT join contas as f on lanc.id_contas = f.id_contas
where f.id_tipo_conta = 1 AND lanc.id_situacao = 1 or lanc.id_situacao = 3
group by lanc.id_contas
```